# Neo4J: efficient neighborhood query

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

What's an efficient way to find all nodes within `N` hops of a given node?  My particular graph isn't highly connected, i.e. most nodes have only degree 2, so for example the following query returns only 27 nodes (as expected), but it takes about a minute of runtime and the CPU is pegged:

```
MATCH (a {id:"36380_A"})-[*1..20]-(b) RETURN a,b;
```

All the engine's time is spent in traversals, because if I just find that starting node by itself, the result returns instantly.

I really only want the set of unique nodes and relationships (for visualization), so I also tried adding `DISTINCT` to try to stop it from re-visiting nodes it's seen before, but I see no change in run time.

Comment: Don't forget to add Labels and then indexes or constraints. You might also want to try to use the new planner with the prefix "cypher 2.1.experimental which should be faster on varlength paths"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, matching the start node alone is really fast and faster if your property is indexed.

However what you are trying to do now is matching the whole pattern in the graph.

Keep your idea of your fast starting point:

```
MATCH (a:Label {id:"1234-a"})
```

once you got it pass it to the rest of the query with WITH

```
WITH a
```

then match the relationships from your fast starting point :

```
MATCH (a)-[:Rel*1..20]->(b)
```

Comment: Not sure how much difference it would make, but the `RETURN` clause also doesn't have to include `a`.  OP already knows what the `a` node is, and this creates the effect of returning node `a` many, many times.

Comment: @KenWilliams Hey. How much faster is the method?

Comment: this method was faster in neo4j2.1.x